# How to limit insertion of value for rows in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i am using below code to add balance to sponser of user but with this code it is add for all sponser. mean its adding balance for sponser of sponser and so on.

i want it add balance for just 3 sponser of sponser

```
function updateDepositBV($id, $deposit_amount)
{
    while($id !="" || $id != "0") {
        if(isMemberExists($id))
        {
            $posid = getParentId($id);
            if($posid == "0")
                break;
            $position = getPositionParent($id);
            $currentBV = MemberExtra::where('user_id', $posid)->first();

            if($position == "R"){
                $new_lbv = $currentBV->left_bv ;
                $new_rbv = $currentBV->right_bv + request()->input('lend_amount');
            }else{
                $new_lbv = $currentBV->left_b + request()->input('lend_amount');
                $new_rbv = $currentBV->right_bv ;
            }
```

i tried :

```
$currentBV = MemberExtra::where('user_id', $posid)->first(3);
```

also with `get(3)` and `take (3)` but not working getting error

Comment: have you tried `$currentBV = MemberExtra::where('user_id', $posid)->skip(0)->take(3)->get();`

Comment: no i tried by replacing first() with get and take

Answer (score 0):

First is only a method to return the first MemberExtra model found.  You have to use `get()` to return a collection of models.

You can get a collection of up to 3 MemberExtra models with `limit(3)` or `take(3)`.

```
MemberExtra::where('user_id', $posid)->limit(3)->get();
```

Then you can loop through, or manipulate, this collection.

Comment: getting error "Property [left_b] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: @waqar I'd say it's error in your question syntax in first place. Maybe it should be `$currentBV->left_bv` instead.

Comment: No my code works perfectly when it's only first() . But I want to limit insersion of balance to only 3 person

Comment: You have to loop through the collection... If you have more than one item, you can't use it as a single item...